Integrating Eclipsestore into Quarkus
I am trying to use the eclipsestore cdi4 integrations with Quarkus. However it seems like Quarkus does not find the beans defined in the dependency.
The main error i get looks like this:
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type org.eclipse.store.integrations.cdi.types.extension.StorageExtension and qualifiers [@Default]
        - injection target: org.eclipse.store.integrations.cdi.types.config.StorageManagerProducer#storageExtension
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.store.integrations.cdi.types.config.StorageManagerProducer], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.eclipse.store.integrations.cdi.types.config.StorageManagerProducer]


I am familiar with the concept of jandex indexes so i thought that the following entries in application.properties will fix the problem:
quarkus.index-dependency.eclipsestore.group-id=org.eclipse.store
quarkus.index-dependency.eclipsestore.artifact-id=eclipse-store-integrations-cdi4

It did not work the beans are still not found. All i got as an output doing quarkus:build was:
2024-09-25 12:03:29,165 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanArchives] (build-46) Failed to index javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV for base-starter-flow-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT@41005828
2024-09-25 12:03:29,165 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.IndexClassLookupUtils] (build-46) Class for name: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
2024-09-25 12:03:29,182 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanArchives] (build-46) Failed to index jakarta.validation.MessageInterpolator$Context: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV for base-starter-flow-quarkus-1.0-SNAPSHOT@41005828
2024-09-25 12:03:29,182 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.IndexClassLookupUtils] (build-46) Class for name: jakarta.validation.MessageInterpolator$Context was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.



According to https://docs.eclipsestore.io/manual/misc/integrations/cdi.html, the CDI extension is a Portable Extension, which is not (and cannot be) supported in Quarkus.
